# How to Implement Pages Feature like YouTube / Other sites?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm still new to Javascript and would like to create a 'pages' feature for comments and replies.

YouTube videos have a very nice pagination feature that pages the comments well.

How do I go about doing this? My current setup is with PHP, Javascript, and MySQL.

Comment: What are your requirements for the _'pages' feature_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube sends an ajax request back to the server and fetches the results which is updated to the page currently viewed. Other sites also use similar technique.

Basic thing you need to know are:

1. pagination requires two main variables. `$page` and `$itemsPerPage`.
2. Using above variable, you will create a query limit
3. You will use this limit in your query to fetch the result of the next page.

Example:

```
$page = (int)$_POST['page'];
$itemsPerPage = 10; //Generally this might be static
$limit = (($page-1)*$itemsPerPage).",".$itemsPerPage;
// For the Page 1, this give 0,10

$query = "SELECT ... LIMIT $limit";
   //Translates to LIMIT 0,10 so takes out the first 10 records or in other words first page
//get the records, creat the markup and echo them
```

Now, as part of Javascript, here is an example of jQuery Post Request

```
$("#yourpageonelink").click(function() {
   $.post("yourpage.php", { 
     page: 1 // I am using static value for demo, but you should get this dynamically
   }, function(data)  { 
      //Now data will get the content returned from the php file
     // So update the div
     $("#mainContainer").html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! Another question if you don't mind: with your code set-up, how should I go about finding the total number of pages to display on HTML (for the user to click through)?

Comment: @TheJagganator I dont know, it depends. Make sure you include enough to read, or ever better give a way to choose how many to display, just like stackoverflow does.

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about how YouTube allows you to page through the comments without leaving the actual page, then this is done via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). A javascript request is sent up to the server requesting a new page of comments.  The server responds with the data and the javsacript then updates the comments area with the new information. All this can be done without redirecting the user to a new page.